# Magento 2: get sub categories with limit

Tags: magento2, category

I have number of sub categories under main category. I have to get only four sub categories of main category. Any solution for this?

Here is the code for get sub categories:

```
$catId = 3; // Parent Category ID
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
$subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
        echo $subcat->getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Snippet:

```
$catId = 3; // Parent Category ID
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
$cnt = 0;
$subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
        $cnt++;
        echo $subcat->getName();
        if($cnt == 4)
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **setPageSize** to limit the categories.

```
$category = $this->_categoryModel->load($categoryId);
$subCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories()->setPageSize(3);
```

Reference [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html)

**Note** - Do not use object manager in phtml file. It's not recommended way instead create Block Class.